# Flickering white screen Ryzen 9 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04

I have tried the patches. I have added 20-radeon.conf.  I ran the xandr command using the output and mode flags. The command was unsuccessful as both modes were not recognized(1920X1080). I using the system for calculations and not for gaming, thus I do not need very fast displays. What is the best way forward?